# Is there a better way to specify occurrence of 0 to 2 times of a certain character in regex than manually writing out all cases?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a regex that looks like this `/^[a-z]+((-|--|_|__)[a-z]+)*$/`. I want it to match any string in kebabCase while also permitting having between 0 to 2 `-` or `_` between words.

so for example I'd want it to match something like this

`test__test--test-test`

is there a better way to specify this than making all of the cases and putting `|` between them?

Comment: Do you mean you want to shorten it? Maybe like [`/^[a-z]+(?:[-_]{1,2}[a-z]+)*$/`](https://regex101.com/r/5EPv4t/1)? Or [`/^(?!.*[-_]{3})[a-z_-]+$/`](https://regex101.com/r/5EPv4t/2)?

Comment: that would match test-_test as well though

Comment: and yes my goal is to make shorter and more maintainable

Comment: `/^[a-z]+(?:([_-])\1?[a-z]+)*$/`

Comment: @Thomas, post it.